# "Raspberry Pi 3 No sound output over hdmi"

Tags: raspberry-pi3, amixer

I connected the Raspberry to my tv via HDMI cable but no sound came out, i tried to install libraries:
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install mpg321
sudo apt-get install lame

and loaded the driver:
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835

and executed the following command:
sudo amixer cset numid=3 2

In the instructions it says that if you are using HDMI choose "2".

When I executed the command it just says:
amixer: Control default open error: No such file or directory

Comment: You might get better answers by asking this question on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all: What are you trying to reproduce?

Then... What does it say if you type: ?

> amixer controls

Also, if you go to /boot/config.txt, what is the value of `dtparam=audio` ? It should be on. 
For more info, maybe check this out: https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Sound